# How to get corresponding user information - FireBase

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I need some help with something.

I am creating an application which allows users to post tasks. When a user saves a task their uid is sent to the database along with the task information. In my database I have a separate child for users which contains all of a users information, i.e name and other stuff.

When my app starts I want to pull all tasks from firebase and according to the uid saved with a task, I want to pull the user information corresponding to that task so that I could set correction information on the cards.

I need help achieving this, thanks.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Yes, i have already implemented a function to reads task from the database. My problem is that i want to pull the specific user information down after pulling down the task.